# RDP to remote Natted machines

Tags: rdp, vnc

I currently have a situation where I have around 20 machines across 7 or so locations where each of those locations is firewalled. We need to be able to pull up a remote desktop on these machines (windows XP and 7 machines).

Currently we are using Logmein Hamachi for access to the machines but would really like to move away from this solution as we have trouble with it crashing and users shutting it down.

We are interested in both hosted and non-hosted solutions. We have a linux server here that could be used to host our own solution if one is available. It is preferable that the solution be relatively light weight (at least when we aren't actually remoting in).

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: The situation is one where we administer a few machines at each site but the IT department administers the rest as well as the network. Unfortunately they are unwilling to open any external ports or allow any server hardware at these sites.

Another update: A possible solution that I have considered is to run a VPN server on our server and setup the clients to use split tunneling. It seems this would work to grant us access but I'm not very familiar with VPNs so I'm not certain.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Shopping Questions are considered Off-Topic here on ServerFault.  Please see the [Help](http://serverfault.com/help) section or [Here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for more info.  **If you are interested in having a way to ask these types of questions** head over to the [IT Shopping Questions Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59278/it-shopping-questions) and post your question as a possible question for the beta and follow the proposal.

Comment: Any real solution is going to require their IT department to do _something_. If they're stonewalling you, go over their heads.

Comment: Yes, a vpn should as long as the aren't blocking your vpn's outgoing  connection.  The routing will be tricky.

Comment: Any solution that works *around* the IT department is likely in violation of some policy and a good way to get in trouble. Setup a rogue VPN to get around IT policy and you might might find yourself shunted from the network completely.

Comment: I may have to do that, Michael. They definitely know our needs, from higher ups, but don't seem willing (or maybe capable) to do what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server 2008R2 or 2012 with Remote Desktop Gateway, in each site, would work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have access to opening ports at the sites.  We are in an odd situation where our company's IT department has control of the site network while we administer a few machines at each site. They are unwilling to allow us to do any network configuration or install any additional hardware at the sites.

Comment: Then you're probably stuck with something that doesn't require firewall configuration, like LogMeIn.

Comment: That would also have been useful information in your question. Don't forget to update it.

Comment: Also, it might be worthwhile to work *with* your IT department rather than around it. If you're in a company where IT and business needs can't meet in the middle, then I feel bad for you.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect this. 

I would really prefer to work with the IT department, however they have decided that we must work around their rules essentially. They still aren't used to having other divisions that actually understand technology apparently.